# Finding root of $x^3-36x^2+405x-1458=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

How can I solve the following equation :

$$x^3-36x^2+405x-1458=0$$

I have tried as :

$$x^3-36x^2+405x-1458=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2(x-36)+405(x-3.6)=0$$

How is to proceed ?

Comment: Look up the closed form solution, replace coefficients, and simplify

Comment: @Coolwater by closed form solution do you mean the expression in the parenthesis ? How is to replace coefficients ?

Comment: I mean these formulas `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+Solve[a+x^3+%2B+b+x^2+%2B+c+x+%2B+d+%3D%3D+0%2C+x]`

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of powers of $3$ in there.  Try $x=3y$, then $$27y^3-324y^2+1215y-1458=0\\y^3-12y^2+45y-54=0$$
Can you find a solution to that, or change it again?

Comment: I am not understanding why have you chosen $x=3y$?

Comment: @ABC prime factorize each coefficient, the factorizations have many 3s in common, I dont why he didnt precede with x= 9y, which is better

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Starting by looking for integer solutions. Every integer solution will necessarily be a divisor of $1458=2\cdot 3^6$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $x=9$ is a solution, you can factor out $(x-9)$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

If we replace $x$ with $y+12$, then $y$ with $3z$, the original problem boils down to solving:
$$ z^3-3z-2=0,$$
whose solutions are obviously given by $z=-1$ and $z=2$, since $z^3-3z+2=(z+1)^2(z-2)$.